# Node Upgrade AWS Lambda: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed

Tags: node.js, docker, aws-lambda, grpc, serverless

I am trying to upgrade the nodeJS version of my lambda functions from [v12](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-end-of-support-for-node-js-12-x-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v3/) to v16. The functions have been deployed via serverless with the application contained in a docker image.

My function is using the GRPC library and the below error pop up when I run the function after upgrade.

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system\nExpected directory: node-v83-linux-x64-glibc\nFound: [node-v72-linux-x64-glibc]\nThis problem can often be fixed by running \"npm rebuild\" on the current system\nOriginal error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/grpc/index.js\n- /var/task/src/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system",
        "Expected directory: node-v83-linux-x64-glibc",
        "Found: [node-v72-linux-x64-glibc]",
        "This problem can often be fixed by running \"npm rebuild\" on the current system",
        "Original error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/grpc/index.js",
        "- /var/task/src/index.js",
        "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
        "- /var/runtime/Runtime.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.js",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:225:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:300:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:34)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

I am just updating the run time in my serverless

```
runtime: nodejs12.x   // changing it to 14 or 16 here
```

and parallely also changing the version in my Docker

```
FROM node:12 as builder        # changed to 14 or 16 as per serverless runtime

# ensure installation
RUN node -v; npm -v

#### Few COPY Command on package.json ###

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile


FROM builder as base
```

The error is also encountered when I changed the version via runtime setting in Lambda.
[AWS Lambda Runtime change screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeFee.png)

Few below steps were tried :

1. Tried upgrading the version via serverless and Dockerfile.
2. Changed runtime setting from AWS.

Comment: Have you checked if the library is part of `node:12` image and not part of `node:14`?

Comment: Hi @HussainMansoor, I see that last supported version for grpc is node 14 as per npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc , Is their any other way to check the same ?

Post this

Comment: @HussainMansoor can you let me know if above understanding is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the `grpc` package was installed using a different version of Node than the one that is loading it. You can probably fix this by rebuilding the docker image from scratch. However, the `grpc` package is deprecated, and does not work on any version of Node greater than 14. The replacement package is `@grpc/grpc-js`.

Comment: Hi @murgatroid99, I am facing this issue even in the nodejs14 version. Also facing this when building on local and rebuilding wherein the version is same.

Comment: My recommendation is to use `@grpc/grpc-js`, which doesn't have this issue at all.

Comment: hi @murgatroid99 , Somewhere we are still using grpc in some dependent libraries so cannot get rid of same. 
 
In local I am using same node version to build and run and still somehow facing the error. The node version is same on my docker file as well.

Rebuilding from scratch by deleting package_lock.json and node-Modules is not helping either. Any idea what we might be missing ?

Comment: To clarify, you are getting the exact same error, with the same "Expected directory" and "Found" lines as in the question?